# What is the best way to simplify the return statement inside the function ? The 'range' field is added to 'myInterval' dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
getSomething() {
 return this.myInterval && this.myInterval.range && this.myInterval.range.caption;
}
```

How would you reduce the number of && checks while keeping the depth of the 'myInterval' object?

Answer (score 1):

Optional chaining would be an option but this feature was just released and is not widely available yet.

You should checkout and see supported browsers and environments.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Your code would look something like this

```
getSomething() {
 return this.myInterval?.range?.caption;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** you just want to return either `caption`, or `null`

You can use this simple utility function that receives the path of the nested property you want, and the object you want to get the nested property from, and returns the nested property if the path exists, or `null` if it does not.

```
const getPath = (p, o) => {
  if (!p || typeof(p) !== "string" || !o || typeof(o) !== "object") {
    return null;
  }
  return p.reduce((xs, x) =>
    (xs && xs[x]) ? xs[x] : null, o)
};
```

You would then use it in your code like

```
getSomething() {
 return getPath(["myInterval","range","caption"], this);
}
```

**NOTE** You can change the default `null` value for any fallback value of your need.